# Who can tell me what's different of the project type in Eclipse CDT?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I just install **CDT plugin** in **Eclipse**. When i start a project by click New menu in Eclipse, it shows lots of **C/C++ project**  type:

such as: `Executable/Excetuable(XL UPC)/Shared Library/Shared Library(XL UPC)....`
What's different between them?

Answer (score 0):

These are essentially "presets" - they have slightly different default build settings. E.g. shared library will pass the linker settings to emit .so instead of executable, XL UPC projects use compiler different then GCC by default, etc.

These settings can be changed after the project is created - but it may require a good understanding of CDT.